# How do I share my location on more than one iOS device?

Tags: ios, icloud, apple-id, sharing, geolocation

To take advantage of Mac-continuity, Safari, Photos, Passbook, and Keychain sharing features, I have to use the same account on all my devices. But, location sharing is also enabled through iCloud and it only allows one device to be specified. I want to share the location of each device at the same time.

All devices are using iOS 8.1.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible using a single Apple ID. If you wish to share the location of each device specifically, you will need to use a unique Apple ID on each device.

Comment: Why would apple require me to use a single apple id to enable the other features but then require different apple id's to share the location of each device? These are conflicting configurations.

Comment: @Ken Because location sharing is meant to be per-person each with their own Apple ID, not per-device, as each person may have many devices but a person only has one physical location.

Answer (score -1):

It's annoying I agree.  But just use the "Find iPhone" app/iCloud web function when logged in, and you should be able to see all your devices.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  This doesn't provide an answer to the OP's question.  They want to share their location and not see the location of their devices.